# Reactjs clientside and Server side both together

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am new in Reactjs. I create architecture using Reactjs. 
When user comes for site and hit url then server.js (server side Rendering) file call. and in browser javascript enable then it's call client side call and if java script disable then run server side. show, How can I achieve this. i take refernce below url:

http://jmfurlott.com/tutorial-setting-up-a-simple-isomorphic-react-app/

Please help me.

Comment: The question is not very clear Ravi, can you elaborate more? Perhaps adding some relevant code into the question might help.

Comment: Please check it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In SSR(Server side rendering) the first render is performed on the server and the rendered HTML is returned to the user unlike in CSR(Client Side Rendering) where a basic html is sent and then react populates the DOM on the client side. Check out this project. They are based on this SSR architecture.

https://github.com/reactGo/reactGo

Comment: Thanks. If any issue in that example.I will ping you.